# Why infrared laser goggle looked orange?

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science, spectroscopy, instrument

So here's the thing, the laser goggle for UV light looked orange-yellow, which was sort of understandable, cause, if one want to block UV light, then the transmitted light ought to stay away from the UV spectra.

However, I suddenly realized that most of the the laser goggle I've seen for infer red light also looked orange-red. This became somewhat confusing. I sort of suspect that it might because the material blocked infer red but not red. Still, why the laser goggle for infer red laser still looked orange-red? What's the reason and common material for this result?

Comment: does the laser goggle specifically block infrared only, or does it also block UV as well? It probably is the latter case.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer because this is safety critical topic and I don't have any citations to back this up beyond others on the forums.  Take this with a grain of salt. The color that a pair of laser goggles is has little to nothing to do with its performance.  If you're blocking a visible laser wavelength, it may imply something about the color of the lenses, but you're really interested in the absorption of a very small waveband, and could care less about all other bands.

Comment: This seems particularly applicable to your examples of UV and IR.  Both of those are outside of the visible spectrum, so the makers really couldn't care less what the color looks like within the visible spectrum.  Remember that many IR lenses are made of materials that completely reflect visual light!